# Implementing message in c++

Tags: c++

As you know, objective-c uses message expression to call member function(method), which means you can dynamically call member function in run-time. 
I wanted to implement this message expression in c++ as class. So any classes can use message expression by inheriting and registering the their member function. 
Here's simple example for what I'm trying to do.

[image]

in SomeClass.cpp

```
// class SomeeClass : public MyMessageExpression

type SomeClass::method_name_of_SomeClass(){
   //code..
   registerFunc(method_name_of_SomeClass) //registerFunc will add the function pointer into the function table  
}
```

And finally you can use like this,

```
SomeClass.sendMessge("method_name_of_SomeClass");
```

The problem I couldn't solve is that how I'm going to cast void pointer into `mothod_name_of_SomeClass`'s function pointer in run-time. How can I set variable function pointer in function table?

In case `mothod_name_of_SomeClas` uses `stdcall` calling convention How can I implement this class?

Comment: Are you asking about virtual polymorphism, or even static polymorphism (see [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) actually?

Comment: I was not asking CRTP(i didn't even know about this) but yes, this was what I'm looking for. Thank you. Then how about virtual function pointer? How did they cast void pointer to function pointer?

Comment: You don't need virtual function pointers along using the CRTP, a simple `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically you have several levels that you can tackle this at...

1. Ignore it, when in rome do as romans do, use `virtual` methods and c++ paradigms
2. Use Objective-C++, this is useful as a shim between Mac OSX gui and a c++ library
3. Use strings as something like selectors... and sort of mock out NSInvocation, use a variadic method like `MyObject::performMethodWithArguments(std::string methodName, ...)` ... this would be logic heavy and sort of painful

probably just learn about virtual methods and function pointers.

Comment: Yes, this might be just useless in c++. Actually, this idea was just came up with curiosity about how objective-c implemented message mechanism and about mechanism of virtual function table. I think I gotta change the question. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that works that may be close enough for you:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename C>
struct MessageExpression
{
    std::map<std::string,void(C::*)(void)> functions;
    void registerFunc(std::string name,void(C::*function)(void))
        { functions[name]=function; }
    void sendMesg(std::string name)
        { (static_cast<C*>(this)->*functions[name])(); }
};

struct SomeClass : public MessageExpression<SomeClass>
{
    void method1() { std::cout << "method1" << std::endl; };
    void method2() { std::cout << "method2" << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass s;
    s.registerFunc("method1",&SomeClass::method1);
    s.registerFunc("method2",&SomeClass::method2);
    s.sendMesg("method1");
    s.sendMesg("method2");
}
```

You can store a void pointer in an array of void pointers but at some point you need to convert it back to the correct member function pointer.  And since that is done in MessageExpression anyway you may as well store the correct kind of pointer in a proper map.

You need to pass &SomeClass::method1 to registerFunc because the compiler won't know about method1 unless you say what namespace it is in.  I am also passing the string - you could use a preprocessor macro to stringify the function name if you want.

The other thing you could do is store std::function in the map.  But then you need to bind the this pointer just before calling it.  I don't see the advantage here - it may make more sense if you bound the this pointer before storing it in the map..

Comment: this code is what i'm try to do with CRTP. Now I have a point of reference. Thank you!